# Attribute Error : Map object has no attribute 'create_map'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, folium

I need some help on this, I try to use folium in my code but keep getting this error message :

> Attribute Error : Map object has no attribute 'create_map'

Here is what I get (and there is not create_map in the list) :

```
dir(folium.Map)

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
 '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
 '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', 
 '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
 '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 
 '_get_self_bounds', '_repr_html_', '_repr_png_', '_to_png', 'add_child' , 
 'add_children', 'add_tile_layer', 'add_to', 'choropleth', 'fit_bounds', 
'get_bounds', 'get_name', 'get_root', 'render', 'save', 'to_dict', 'to_json']
```

---

The code is :

```
import folium
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
map_osm.create_map(path='osm.html')
```

P.S : folium version 0.5.0 // Python 3.6.4

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation about `create_map` since version `0.2.0`

Comment: Yeah you're right....I guess it was replaced...as I found in some other threads a recommendation to use createmap instead of create_map !

Comment: Thank you Chrisz ! It worked

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `save` method to save maps as HTML.

e.g

```
map_osm.save('osm.html')
```

It is also mentioned in the output of `dir(folium.Map)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This question seems easy for me:

```
import folium
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
map_osm.save('/Users/YourName/Desktop/osm.html') #here need to be 
        full path
```

And then you can find a osm.html in the directory you put. Open with your internet explorer and then you can see the map.

[image: Map you can see]

Answer (score 0):

```
import folium
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
map_osm.save('osm.html')
```

#here you will find html file at same folder of your script